# Why the color of text is blue on bootstrap col ? and how to redesign my page with only Bootstrap css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf, web-frontend

I have worked on application and i am not strong in front end so i wanted to design a menu page like tiles just with Bootstrap but the result is not like expected.

Can any one show me how or where to find tutorials to design a simple just with css.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ANSWER:

> Why the color of text is blue on bootstrap col?

Default color for anchor tag. You can change it to any color your want.

```
<style>
 a{ color: hex code | color name | rgb values }

 a{ color: red }

</style>
```

> How to re-design my page with only Bootstrap css?

Please refer to the below links:

**Examples:**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/

**Bootstrap Components**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/alerts/

Comment: thank you, i used your code to re color the a tag text , but i kept the divs and i just changed the font + background color. i solve my problem with out those links thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the result, i choose only two colors in order of those choosen before and i changed the font to Century Gothic.
also i added an image to the background.
[image]

Comment: Put some padding to the div. 

padding: 5px; or 8px;

reduce font size to : font-size: 12px; or 11px;

It will look better.